# 3D colour interpolation Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, interpolation

Firstly I'm sorry if this is a duplicate!

To explain the situation, I have developing an application that will display a 3D, real time model of an object. On this model I have a series of pressure sensors which will relay the information to my application. Each pressure will then be assigned a colour to produce a 3D pressure map on the surface of my model. I have 144 pressure sensors and around 21000 vertices on my mesh. Each sensor will be assigned an RGB colour.

Please can someone help me understand how I can use barycentric interpolation to interpolate the known colours (144 of them) across the rest of my model?

This website nicely shows what I'm trying to achieve: https://codeplea.com/triangular-interpolation however I cannot find anything that helps me in 3 dimensions.

Help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, thank you for the nice page about barycentric interpolation you provided in the question!

Secondly, you may triangulate your model with the sensor in every point, and interpolate between sensor values inside every triangle, no matter if it's 2D or 3D -- triangle is a triangle. With barycentric you'll get nice matching colours along every edge, the whole model is going to look very cool.

Comment: Hi Lenik,  Thank you for the response.  Would there be any chance you could provide an example code snippet?  I'm sorry - I've been looking at this for about a week and going mad!

Comment: @adamturner what exactyl code snippet are you looking for? you have 144 sensors, make a "rough" model of your object, that contains only the vertices that have the sensors. use barycentric interpolation to calculate colours for that "rough" model. then map the calculated colours to the vertices of your 21000 vertice model by building the normals or using the closest point to the model vertice or any other method you like. I'm just not sure which part you have trouble with, please, clarify.